# How to remove "carrier title","method title" from checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: checkout, shipping, onepage-checkout, magento2.3, shipping-methods

I am using 2.3.1 and the pearl theme. Currently my shipping looks like this:
[image: old shipping]
However, since we don't let our customers pick the carrier it seems confusing and I would like it to look like this:

[image: new shipping]

I've been digging around and have looked at

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
 <your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

but neither of these seem to have what I'm looking for. How can I remove these labels? 

EDIT per comments:
If shipping.html is the right place what code should I edit to remove the labels?

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html is correct but be sure to check if the file is overwritten by a module or your theme

Comment: Where exactly in that file am I looking to change it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

After more digging the code I wanted to remove was in:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html
```

Comment: To expand on this answer. `shipping-method-list.html` contains the table headers. `shipping-method-item.html` contains the table data. Both need to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Version 2 or more than 2.3
File Path: `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\shipping-method-list.html`

After change the content please run the basic Commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```